# Blender 3.0 shadow catcher really slow

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shadowcatcher

Since the new Blender 3.0 version came out, it seems that they use a new shadow catcher in cycles, which is much slower than in version 2.93, which makes it unusable for me as the render times increase extremely (even on good hardware (RTX 3070, Ryzen 3700X)). Is there any way to use the 2.93 shadow catcher in 3.0, because the new Cycles X is faster than in 2.93 but not with the new shadow catcher.

Answer (score 1):

The new shadow catcher is not "just" a shadow catcher, it takes indirect lighting into account as well - therefore it's slower than the old one. It makes a difference however if you have the Shadow Catcher pass enabled in the Render Layers - when it is disabled, it only uses an approximation. When it's enabled, it captures all indirect light interactions.

See the note here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/object_data.html